# How Can I Get position of 'o' in name 'John' from employee table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a small application program and I am stuck here.
What to do now? pls suggest me something kind of things and stuff

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `CHARINDEX('o', 'John')`

Answer (score 0):

try this

1) if your name is hardcoded

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('o', 'John')
```

2) use this if you getting Employee name from table

```
 SELECT CHARINDEX('o', Emp_Name) FROM Employee WHERE Emp_Name LIKE 'John'
```